# Python ModuleNotFoundError Testsuite (Import Error)

Tags: python, python-import

When I run a file with some tests (ex. python **test_website_loads.py**) the test runs perfectly and there are no issues, but when I try the testsuite (ex. python **test_suite.py**), the next error occurs:

```
    from special_module.special_module_file import Special_Class
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'specialmodule'
```

My directory is as follows:

```
test_suite.py
tests/
  __init__.py
  test_website_loads.py
  special_module/
    __init__.py
    special_module_file.py
```

In my special_module_file I have a class with name **Special_Class** and I am importing such directory in my **test_website_loads.py** as:

```
from special_module.special_module_file import Special_Class
```

My **test_suite.py** code is:

```
import unittest
import HtmlTestRunner
from tests.test_website_loads import Test_Website_Loads

init_tests = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(Test_Website_Loads)

test_suite = unittest.TestSuite([
    init_tests
])

runner = HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output='reports', report_title='Test Report')
runner.run(test_suite)
```

And my **test_website_loads.py** code is:

```
import unittest
import HtmlTestRunner
from special_module.special_module import Special_Class

class Test_Website_Loads(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        special = Special_Class()

    def ...():
        ...

    def tearDown():
        ...

if __name__ == "__main__":

    unittest.main(
        testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output='init')
    )
```

In summary there are 3 files (A, B, C). A calls B, B calls C. When I run B, it correctly imports C. But when running A, B throws the ModuleNotFoundError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because it's located in the `tests` directory, but you're running `test_suite.py` from the parent directory of `tests`. The reason why it worked when you ran `test_website_loads.py` is because you were running it from within the `tests` directory. When resolving imports, the Python interpreter checks a series of locations for the module, starting with the current directory and then moving to other locations such as those in your PYTHONPATH environment variable, and the `site-packages` directory in your Python install location.

I duplicated this on my system but changed the import statement to `tests.special_module.special_module_file` and it worked. If you don't like this solution, you will need to change the location of the `special_module` directory or [add it to your PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) or something similar.

**Edit:** In response to your comment below, I assume your `test_suite.py` file looks something like this:

```
from tests.test_website_loads import some_function, some_class

result = some_function()
obj = some_class()
```

This still runs into the problem described above, because the Python interpreter is still being run in the top-level directory. When it searches for modules, it searches the current directory where it only finds `test_suite.py` and `tests/`. Then it checks your PYTHONPATH environment variable. If it still finds nothing, it will check then installation-dependent default location (such as the `site-packages` directory), and if no such module is found, it throws an exception. I think the best solution would be to add `special_module` to the PYTHONPATH environment variable as described in the link I included above. Otherwise, you could create a symbolic link to the module in the top-level directory with `ln -s tests/special_module special_module`, assuming that you're running on a UNIX-like system. However, this would not be considered best practice; the first method is preferred.

Comment: You are correct indeed, I didn't write an important part, I'm not importing the special module in the test_suite.py, I'm calling it from the test_website_loads.py (In summary, test_suite.py calls test_website_loads.py and  test_website_loads calls the special module but it fails

Comment: Okay, that does help. Could you edit your original question to include this information? Also, if you could add the code from test_suite.py that you are using to call test_website_loads.py, that could also help.

Comment: I believe the main issue is still the one I described in my answer, because even though test_website_loads.py is located within the same directory as the special_module directory, the Python interpreter is still being run from within the parent directory, so it still doesn't know where to find the special_module directory; now it's just a matter of finding a solution.

Comment: @ArturoAviles I edited my original answer to reflect your correction. It should solve your problems. If not, please let me know.