# Can I use a python module's main for testing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-module

I'm developing a Python library on Python 3.8.2 and I would like to run a module as main for testing purposes. When I try, I get a ModuleNotFound error.

Here's my library structure:

```
.
├── foo
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── bar.py
│   └── quux
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── corge.py
│       └── garply.py
├── main.py
```

bary.py:

```
def baz():
    print("baz")
```

corge.py

```
from foo.quux.garply import *


def grault():
    waldo()
    print("grault")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    grault()
```

garply.py

```
def waldo():
    print("waldo")
```

main.py

```
from foo.bar import *
from foo.quux.corge import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    baz()
    grault()
```

(All `__init__.py` files are empty)

When I run `main.py`, it works.

```
$ python main.py
baz
waldo
grault
```

If I try to run `corge.py`, I get the following error:

```
$ python foo/quux/corge.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo/quux/corge.py", line 1, in <module>
    from foo.quux.garply import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'
```

It doesn't matter what my current working directory is, it always gives this error.

```
$ cd foo/quux/
$ python corge.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "corge.py", line 1, in <module>
    from foo.quux.garply import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'
```

While I was testing this, I created a new PyCharm project with PyCharm 2020.1 and implemented the structure I described. To my surprise, it works with with the default detected run configuration.

I tried using the venv that PyCharm automatically creates, but it still did not work. It does not work if I directly copy/paste the command and use their CWD. It does not work with the terminal built into PyCharm. It *only* works with the PyCharm Run button.

Am I doing something wrong with my module structure? If so, what could PyCharm be doing to make this work? If not, why does it not work outside of PyCharm?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python ModuleNotFoundError Testsuite (Import Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48329498/python-modulenotfounderror-testsuite-import-error)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+modulenotfounderror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python needs to know the directory where `foo` is located in order to import it.  `sys.path` lists the directories where python will search.

When you install a package, the installer worries about doing that - usually by placing the module in a well-known directory or adding the install package path to `sys.path`.

When you run a script, python automatically adds that script's path to `sys.path`, so when you run `main.py`, you will find `foo`.

*How to run as module as `__main__`*

One option is to make a package installable (setup.py, wheels, etc....) and use develop mode (["pip install --editable ./" vs "python setup.py develop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30306099/pip-install-editable-vs-python-setup-py-develop) for some discussion). That's what I do when I am developing something I plan on making available to others.

Another is to add your directory to PYTHONPATH, perhaps even as you run the program. On linux that would be

```
PYTHONPATH=path/to/fooproject:$PYTHONPATH python foo/quux/corge.py
```

Yet another, and I do this one too, is to hack the path in the module itself.  `__file__` gives your filename relative to current working directory and you know how deep you are in your package hierarchy. So you can just make `__file__` absolute and peel off a couple of directory names

corge.py

```
import sys
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # I'm two levels deep in the package so package directory is
    packagedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
        "..", ".."))
    sys.path.insert(0, packagedir)
    import foo
```

Finally, don't do it in the first place. When you run `corge.py` as a script, it gets a different namespace `__main__` than `foo.bar.corge` imported as a module. Its global variables / classes / functions are loaded twice and you get different ones depending on whether you call them through the `__main__` namespace or `foo.bar.corge`.

Its better to take anything you are tempted to put into a main in `corge.py`, make them separate scripts. For instance, you could add `def main()` to your modules. In `main.py` you could add an option `--run foo.bar.corge` telling main to import `corge.py` and run its `main()`. [`argparse` subcommands](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) can be used for this.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you! My original plan was to use this to run unit tests, would it be appropriate to define a `test()` method in the module, or should that be handled differently?

Comment: Yes, you can put the tests with the code - I'm not sure that its common practice but it wouldn't raise an eyebrow if you did. But you are putting code in a module that doesn't need to be there in normal runtime. I've tended to use `nose` or just the vanilla unittest that comes with python (pytest is another option) and I separate them into a separate directory. I think you should do whatever is the most normal thing for your test framework.

Answer (score 1):

Your invocation of `main.py` works because Python will look in immediate sub-directories for modules.  Any module in any other location that wants to import `foo.yadda.whatever` will have to find `foo` by searching your `PYTHONPATH`.  Therefore you need to add the parent directory of `foo` to your `PYTHONPATH`.